# How to use set render region with python, without setting borders?

Tags: python, rendering

When I use the Set Render Region via the search menu, I instantly get the setting where I can set the region with mouseclicks, but when I run the following code

```
import bpy

#override context, only to run command from text editor:
override_context = bpy.context.copy()
area = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D"][0]
override_context['window'] = bpy.context.window
override_context['screen'] = bpy.context.screen
override_context['area'] = area
override_context['region'] = area.regions[-1]
override_context['scene'] = bpy.context.scene
override_context['space_data'] = area.spaces.active

bpy.ops.view3d.render_border(override_context, wait_for_input=True)
```

nothing happens. I dont want to hardcode the borders, I want it to work exactly like when I use the Set Render Region command from the search menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EXEC_DEFAULT` is used by default, running only the `execute()` method, but you may want the operator to take user interaction with `INVOKE_DEFAULT` which will also call `invoke()` if existing:

```
bpy.ops.view3d.render_border(override_context,'INVOKE_DEFAULT', wait_for_input=True)
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html

BTW, You can use [new context override method](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override), which makes code a little bit clear:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

area = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D"][0]

with context.temp_override(area=area, region=area.regions[-1]):
    bpy.ops.view3d.render_border('INVOKE_DEFAULT', wait_for_input=True)
```